# Javascript: Script de alertas en cuenta corriente bancaria

Tags: javascript

Resulta que estoy tratando de diseñar un script para una pagina html de depósitos en cuenta corriente, que me indique cuando un numero de cuenta es superior a un valor dado, o un monto se pasa de cierta cantidad. lo cierto es que el script no me esta funcionando (por lo pronto cuando utilizo node para ver el funcionamiento, no me permite y me dice "ReferenceError: document is not defined", pero creo que es porque Node.js no proporciona un entorno de navegador, es un tiempo de ejecución del lado del servidor, por lo que no podemos usar la documentvariable en Node.)y no puedo darme cuenta si es falla de diseño o una cuestión de mala escritura. Así que apelo a ustedes a ver si pueden ver alguna obviedad que yo no estoy viendo. les adjunto los códigos correspondientes:

**Código html:**

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Banco del Plata</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="titulo">Banco del Plata S.A.</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="container">
            <h2>Estado de Cuenta Corriente</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th>Cuenta Numero</th>
                        <th>Depositos</th>
                        <th>Extracciones</th>
                        <th>Saldo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tabla-Clientes">
                    <tr class="cliente">
                        <td class="info-nombre">Pablo</td>
                        <td class="info-dni">14271922</td>
                        <td class="info-direccion">L.Maria Campos 152</td>
                        <td class="info-cuenta_numero">95</td>
                        <td class="info-depositos">1100</td>
                        <td class="info-extracciones">50</td>
                        <td class="info-saldo">950</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="cliente">
                        <td class="info-nombre">Andrea</td>
                        <td class="info-dni">23456772</td>
                        <td class="info-direccion">Moldes 1526</td>
                        <td class="info-cuenta_numero">200</td>
                        <td class="info-depositos">2000</td>
                        <td class="info-extracciones">1000</td>
                        <td class="info-saldo">1000</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="cliente">
                        <td class="info-nombre">Martin</td>
                        <td class="info-dni">17253662</td>
                        <td class="info-direccion">San Martin 1950</td>
                        <td class="info-cuenta_numero">98</td>
                        <td class="info-depositos">3000</td>
                        <td class="info-extracciones">500</td>
                        <td class="info-saldo">2500</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="cliente">
                        <td class="info-nombre">Anselmo</td>
                        <td class="info-dni">25336745</td>
                        <td class="info-direccion">Orellana 2756</td>
                        <td class="info-cuenta_numero">99</td>
                        <td class="info-depositos">4500</td>
                        <td class="info-extracciones">200</td>
                        <td class="info-saldo">4300</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="cliente">
                        <td class="info-nombre">Marcos</td>
                        <td class="info-dni">45762335</td>
                        <td class="info-direccion">Entre Rios 556</td>
                        <td class="info-cuenta_numero">97</td>
                        <td class="info-depositos">22500</td>
                        <td class="info-extracciones">600</td>
                        <td class="info-saldo">21900</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="js/principal.js" defer></script> 
</body>
```

**Código javascript:**

```
var clientes = document.querySelector(".cliente");

    for(var i = 0; i< clientes.length;i++){
        var cliente = clientes[i];
        
        var tdCuentaNumero = cliente.querySelector(".info-cuenta_numero");
        var cuentanumero = tdCuentaNumero.textContent;
        
        var tdDepositos = cliente.querySelector(".info-depositos");
        var depositos = tdDepositos.textContent;

        var tdExtracciones = cliente.querySelector(".info-extracciones");
        var extracciones = tdExtracciones.textContent;

        var tdSaldo = cliente.querySelector(".info-saldo");
        var saldo = tdSaldo.textContent;

        cuentanumeroEsValido = true;
        depositoEsValida = true;

if((cuentanumero < 0)||(cuentanumero > 100)){
    console.log("Cuenta Incorrecta");
    tdCuentaNumero.textContent = "Cuenta incorrecta";
    cuentanumeroEsValido = false;
    cliente.classList.add("Cliente-incorrecto");
}

if((depositos < 0)||(depositos > 10000)){
    console.log("Deposito incorrecto");
    tdDepositos.textContent = "Deposito incorrecto";
    depositoEsValida = false;
    cliente.classList.add("Cliente-incorrecto");
}

if(cuentanumeroEsValido && depositoEsValida){
    var saldo = (depositos - extracciones);
    tdSaldo.textContent = saldo.toFixed(2);
}
```

}

Comment: Node == servidor, no puedes abrir una página con node. Por qué no abres la página directamente en el navegador?? Si es html + js puro, no hay ningún problema en abrirla con tu navegador...

Comment: Y como la abro directamente?. Parece una obviedad pero no lo veo...!

Comment: Pues click derecho en tu .html, abrir con -> chrome (o firefox o lo que uses)